# Writing code for JS and Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to write a module of code which can be used with Javascript for the client side browser and Kotlin for a Java desktop application and Android app.

The main logic manipulates a bitmap/png file.

Is there a way which I can write an interface to be used and have different implementations of the interface for JS and Kotlin?

For example, write a wrapper class for an image (load from image, set pixels, get pixels) in Java (using BufferedImage) and JS (using Canvas)?

I'm new here so if anything doesn't make sense or needs more clarification, please let me know!

Comment: See here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible to do that. This answer is a generic Java and JavaScript answer; there may also be a Kotlin-specific approach, see [the link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) in [zsmb13's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366304/writing-code-for-js-and-java/48366351#comment83719248_48366304). But the generic Java and JavaScript approach would be:

1. Write your interface around `BufferedImage` in Java
2. Write your interface around `canvas` in JavaScript
3. Write your manipulation code using that interface in JavaScript
4. On the browser, your manipulation code would run directly on the browser's JavaScript engine
5. In the Java app, you'd run your JavaScript code using [`javax.script`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) to run it in Nashorn (or Rhino on older Java environments).

Whether it's the best solution to your problem is something only you can decide, but yes, you *can* do it.